# How to manipulate Woocommerce product price on front end?

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, shopify, liquid

guys, how are you doing?

I'm migrating from Shopify to Woocommerce, and on Shopify I had a custom code that shows the product price divided by 12x, that is the maximum amount of installments that we accept.

For reference the code that I used there was this: `{{current_variant.price |times:1.1979| divided_by: 12| money }}`.

In this code I:
**1)** got the price of the current selected variant ( `current _variant.price`);
**2)** multiplied by the installments taxes (`times:1.1979`);
**3)** and divided it by the 12 maximum installments (`divided_by: 12`).

How can I do the same thing in Woocommerce? I mean, of course I'm not able to use Liquid as in Shopify, so I guess I'll need to use PHP or JS, thats alright.

And I can't use plugin because later on I have a full table that calculates each installment (from 1x to 12x) and show the final value to the client, so I kinda need to understand the logic by this simpler example that I pasted.

The idea that I'm trying to execute is `price * interests / max. installments number`. PHP is really not my strong suit, sorry for maybe being not that assertive.

Thank you, so much!

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do here. Do you actually need to set/manipulate the price WC will use for a product, when it gets put into the cart? Or do you just need to _display_ something to the user, without affecting any of the actual cart / price calculation logic? What _are_ those “installments”? Is that the actual quantity of the product the user will order, or … what?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you would like the installment price to be displayed beneath the product price on both simple and variable products.

You can use jQuery to add an element underneath the product price. To populate this element with the correct data you can use a PHP function that will calculate the installment price based on the product price. (In this case called `get_installment_price`)

Since you would have to recalculate the installment price for a variable product each time the variation changes you can call that PHP function via AJAX each time the hidden input `variation_id` changes. This hidden input is used by WooCommerce to store which variation is currently selected.

The following code should do the trick:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'show_installment_price_underneath_product_price' );
function show_installment_price_underneath_product_price() {

    global $product;
    //Get the installment price for simple products
    $installment_price = $product->is_type('variable') == false ? get_installment_price( $product ) : 0;

    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

        // Check if product is variable
        if( $('input.variation_id').length ) {

            // If so, calculate the installment price each time the variation changes
            $('input.variation_id').change( function(){
                if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ) {

                    jQuery.ajax( {

                        url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: { 
                            action: 'get_installment_price', 
                            variation_id: $('input.variation_id').val()
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('.woocommerce-variation-price').siblings('.installment-price').remove();
                            $('.woocommerce-variation-price').after('<div class="installment-price"><p>Price per installment: ' + data + '</p></div>');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        // Else use the installement price we've calculated for simple product
        } else {
            let installmentPrice = '<?php echo $installment_price; ?>';
            $('.summary p.price').after('<div class="installment-price"><p>Price per installment: ' + installmentPrice + '</p></div>');
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
    
add_action('wp_ajax_get_installment_price' , 'get_installment_price');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_installment_price','get_installment_price');
function get_installment_price( $product = null ) {

    $variation_id = isset( $_POST['variation_id'] ) ? intval( $_POST['variation_id'] ) : null;
    $product = $variation_id ? wc_get_product( $variation_id ) : $product;

    //Make your installment calculations here
    $installment_price = $product->get_price() * 1.1979 / 12;

    $formatted_installment_price = wc_price( $installment_price, array( 'currency' => get_woocommerce_currency() ) );

    if ( $variation_id ) { // This is the output for the AJAX call (variable product)
        echo $formatted_installment_price;
        wp_die();
    } else { // This is the output for the simple product
        return $formatted_installment_price;
    }
}
```

This should be added to the functions.php of your child theme or via a plugin like Code Snippets.

Comment: If this answer works for you could you mark the answer as accepted, and possibly vote it up? Thank you in advance!